# Change timezone in displayed time

Tags: ios, swift, datetime

I'm trying to show the current time to my user in a UILabel, Swift 5.

I am using the following code to display the current time, which works:

```
import UIKit

class FlightViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var UTCTime: UILabel!
    
    var timer = Timer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UTCTime.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .none)
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector:#selector(self.tick) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func tick() {
        UTCTime.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .short)
    }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */
```

This displays the current time for the region set in the device's settings, but I'd like to display the current time for UTC in a UILabel. But I simply cannot find out how to achieve this.

Does anyone have some pointers?

Comment: Use an instance of `DateFormatter`, set its timezone.

Comment: Thank you for your pointer, I got it figured out with the help of another fellow user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same code in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1415241-localizedstring) (the Discussion paragraph) and setting the timezone should do the trick.

```swift
extension DateFormatter {

    static func utcLocalizedString(from: Date, dateStyle: Style, timeStyle: Style) -> String {
        let utcDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        utcDateFormatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
        utcDateFormatter.dateStyle = dateStyle
        utcDateFormatter.timeStyle = timeStyle
        utcDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        return utcDateFormatter.string(from: from)
    }
}

// example

let now = Date()

let nowAsString = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: now, dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .short) 
print(nowAsString) // 4:42 PM

let utcNowAsString = DateFormatter.utcLocalizedString(from: now, dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .short)
print(utcNowAsString) // 2:42 PM

// usage in you view controller

import UIKit

class FlightViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var UTCTime: UILabel!

    var timer = Timer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UTCTime.text = DateFormatter.utcLocalizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .none)
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector:#selector(self.tick) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func tick() {
        UTCTime.text = DateFormatter.utcLocalizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .short)
    }
}
```

Please note that in the example every second a new date formatter is created; a better approach would be to create a single date formatter (like it has been done in the extension) and use always that one.

Comment: Thanks Mario, but I get the following errors:

Declaration is only valid at file scope
Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'none'
Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'short'
Type 'DateFormatter' has no member 'utcLocalizedString'

I have changed the datestyle and timestyle to .none and .short respectively..
What am I doing wrong? Rather new to app coding too.

Comment: Without having the full code is hard to say but it looks like you put the extension inside your view controller (?) class. Is that the case?

Comment: I wasn't completely sure where to place your code snippet, but after apparently I missed one }. Moving it outside the class (so all the way at the end of the FlightViewController.swift) indeed removed most errors, but now I get two new errors, both being: "Expressions are not allowed at the top level". these are shown at "print(nowAsString) // 4:42 PM" and at "print(nowAsString) // 2:42 PM".

Comment: Because you can’t print in the global scope (outside a view controller for example), move the lines from let now = ... until the end to you viewDidLoad method.

Comment: I’ll try that later tonight or tomorrow morning and come back with the result. Thanks alot for your help so far, much appreciated!

Comment: It works, however it doesn't print and update to my label. I tried adding a new IBoutlet with the utcLocalizedString as name but that didn't help either. It does print the correct time (UTC needs to be GMT btw, UTC isn't known as a timezone identifier in Swift apparently :-)  ) in the Xcode debugger, but just not in my UILabel. I feel stupid now for not figuring this out

Comment: You're right, instead of the identifier init you should use the abbreviation init (it was working anyway for me). For the label issue I don't quite get it. You should just assign the value to the text property. `UTCTime.text = DateFormatter.utcLocalizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .short)` like you already did. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi Mario, it works! At first the simulator crashed immediately upon loading the app, and terminated with an 'uncaught exception of type NSException'. After some research it turned out I still had an old IBOutlet connected between an UILabel and the ViewController. After removing that one it worked straight away. Thank you so much for all your effort and time, I really appreciate it. I learned a lot from it :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want all your dates in the app to be for the same time zone, you can use

```
NSTimeZone.default = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
```